# Deriving parallel transport equations

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, vector-spaces, tensors, general-relativity

From Wald's General Relativity page 37,

[image]

> It is easiest to compute the change in $v^a$ when we return to $p$ by letting $\omega_a$ be an arbitray dual vector field and finding the change in the scalar $v^a\omega_a$ as we traverse the loop.

1) Where is the vector $v^a$ in the picture above?

2) Why do they consider $\omega_a$?

> For small $\Delta t$ the change, $\delta_1$, in $v^a\omega_a$ on the first leg of the path,
>   $$\delta_1 = \Delta t \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(v^a\omega_a)|_{(\Delta t/2,0)}$$
>
> where, by evaluating the derivative at the midpoint, we have ensured that this expression is accurate to second order in $\Delta t$. We may rewrite $\delta_1$ as
>   $$ \delta_1 = \Delta t T^b \triangledown_b (v^a\omega_a)|_{(\Delta t/2,0)}$$

3) How can we introduce the $T^b \triangledown_b$?? I do not see where this came from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The vector $v^a$ is just an arbitrary vector at $p$

[image]

2. It is just a convenient step, you will see how it pays off later in the development. At this point, just note that by introducing $\omega_a$, we can build the quantity $v^a\omega_a$, which is a scalar, and easier to work with: one less index to worry about
3. The chain rule

$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial t} = \left(\frac{\partial x^b(t, s)}{\partial t}\right)_s\frac{\partial}{\partial x^b} = T^b \partial_b
$$

where

$$
T^b \stackrel{.}{=} \left(\frac{\partial x^b(t, s)}{\partial t}\right)_s
$$

is the tangent to the curves of constant $s$

Comment: 3) I still cant see how to apply the chain rule

Comment: @Permian Forget the arguments

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
$$

Comment: I dont uderstand how you can just say $T^b \stackrel{.}{=} \left(\frac{\partial x^b(t, s)}{\partial t}\right)_s$?. I understand the reasoning for the RHS but I cannot see how we can call this $T$ and say its just a tensor

Comment: @Permian I never said it was a tensor, you can call it whatever convenient way you prefer

Comment: Ill give it to you anyway

Comment: @Permian If you are not convinced with the answer, you shouldn't marked it as accepted, that will probably other users of giving you better alternatives